# Invoke a method by name on a string

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I have the following higher-order function:

```
public function function Method (required string name, args=[]) {
    return function (object) {
        return invoke(object, name, args);
    };
}
```

Example use:

```
['abc', 'defg'].map(Method('len')); // [3, 4]
```

Unfortunately, that example is broken. When the first argument to `invoke` is a string, it is interpreted as the name of a component. Is there a way of implementing `Method` that avoids this problem?

Comment: Do we have to call the function `method` ?

Comment: I don't think you can overcome this method overloading issue. You will have to detect if argument `object` is an instance of String and switch to a static instruction based on argument `name`.

Comment: When is the first argument to invoke a string?

Comment: Adding to Alex's comments, according to [the docs](https://cfdocs.org/invoke), `invoke()` isn't designed to work with arbitrary objects that way (even though it might work with some). It's designed to work with a specific subset - java/.net/webservice/etc.  So while a string *is* technically a java object, the function will ignore that and always handles strings as a component *name*.

Comment: I'd say the answer is "no". Adobe hard wired strings to always be handled as component names. AFAIK, there is no elegant way around that.